# How to change main folder name permamently in django

Tags: django, pycharm

I want to change main folder name in django(folder with manage.py), because I think current title makes some issues while i try run it on Heroku ("app crashed").
Current title:  ShoppingList 2.0 
But when i change it to for example ShoppingList2, 
[in PyCharm it looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xepd7.png)

I want to have only "ShoppingList2" without old name in brackets.

Comment: the problem isn't with the main directory because it should work even when renamed unless you have full path to a resource set somewhere. you will have to modify your code to use relative names rather than full path because heroku deploys your application in a directory called `app` and as much as i know there is no ability to rename that folder on heroku without messing up your deployment

Comment: Here are the [instructions to rename the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/renaming-projects.html). If you are still getting errors, you should post them here - I think the Pycharm project name is cosmetic and won't affect how the code runs.

Comment: Ok, I will try yours suggestions, thank you